# Map json data to java bean

Tags: java, json, dictionary, javabeans

Java: Json library to map json data to java bean.

As beanutil's describe and populate method is there any java library which takes input json object and respective java bean and map json data into java bean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyJavaBean bean = gson.fromJson(strJson,MyJavaBean.class);
```

Comment: using gson can we also convert xml data into json ? i want to reduce steps all in one like gson.fromJson(strxml,MyJavaBean.class);

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You'd need to use [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for that.

Comment: gson seems to desrialize through fields not setters, would anyone know any desrializer working through setters?